# Nautilus / Gnome Files says there is no app installed for any file type unless launched from console

Tags: gnome, nixos, nautilus

As the title says. I can't open any file using nautilus.

[image: dialog that is showing]

When I click on *Select App* on the dialog above it shows some irrelevant applications instead of Gnome Text Editor, for example. (Of course I have it installed)

Same thing happens when I try to open image or other file.

**But**

When I launch it from console, it works flawlessly

[image: another dialog]

I use NixOS by the way. Also the logs:

```
** Message: 17:17:35.425: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:59967): WARNING **: 17:17:35.591: Unable to create connection for session-wide Tracker indexer: The name org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: How are you launching it when you're *not* running it from the console? Most likely you're not running the same executable in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for this question @l0b0! I was running it it from [wofi](https://sr.ht/~scoopta/wofi/) in [drun](https://man.archlinux.org/man/wofi.7.en#MODES) mode. After trying different launcher ([fuzzel](https://codeberg.org/dnkl/fuzzel) in my case) nautilus works correctly.